# Is a rope wave a perfectly transverse wave?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves

[image]

When i create a disturbance in a rope.What is happening at the particle level.I imagine the particles and the forces on the particles like this:
[image]

According to my model there should be some horizontal motion as well.Can i say no mechanical wave is 100% transverse?

Comment: How do the displacements scale with the amplitude? Is it possible that the transverse displacement scales with the amplitude but the longitudinal one scales with its square? In that case, the wave would be 'completely transverse' in the low-amplitude limit.

Answer (score 1):

When you first start moving the end of the rope, there will be points along the rope that are not yet moving, and have not experienced the greater tension that results from your motion. It stands to reason that as these points first "feel" the wave, they will move towards the source of the wave (where the tension is greater) as well as transversely.

If that reasoning is sound, then indeed a transverse wave on a rope is not purely transverse.